# Clebsch-Gordan coefficients: General Expression Does Not Match Specific Expression

Tags: special-functions, physics

The expression `ClebschGordan[{2, 0}, {4, 0}, {2, 0}]` yields the correct result of `Sqrt[2/7]`.

However the expression `ClebschGordan[{2, 0}, {l2, 0}, {2, 0}]/. l2 -> 4` yields `Indeterminate`. Indeed, `ClebschGordan[{2, 0}, {l2, 0}, {2, 0}]` evaluates to an algebraic expression `numerator/((-4 + l2) (2 - l2)!)` where `numerator/.l2 -> 4` evaluates to `Sqrt[2/7]`. This is indeed indeterminate.

Interestingly, the expression `ClebschGordan[{l2, 0}, {2, 0}, {2, 0}] /. l2 -> 4` gives the correct result, and `ClebschGordan[{l2, 0}, {2, 0}, {2, 0}]` leads to a different algebraic expression that has the same values for `0<=l2<4` and the correct value for `l2->4`.

This would appear to be a minor bug, as it violates the simplest symmetry of the Clebsch-Gordan coefficients.

Comment: Weirder even is the fact that substituting your values in the pre-calculated completely symbolic expression returns the correct result: `ClebschGordan[{j, m}, {j1, m1}, {j2, m2}] /. {j -> 2, m -> 0, j1 -> 4,  m1 -> 0, j2 -> 2, m2 -> 0}` returns `Sqrt[2/7]`. The substitution can also be done stepwise and the correct result is still obtained. Odd behavior indeed.

Answer (score 3):

An argument could be made that the result being returned by `ClebschGordan[]` is *[generically correct](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/MathematicalFunctions.html#16439)*; that is, the expression that comes from the [hypergeometric representation](https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/ClebschGordan/02/) of the Clebsch-Gordan coefficient is correct except at a countable number of values.

In particular,

```
ClebschGordan[{2, 0}, {l2, 0}, {2, 0}] // FullSimplify
   Piecewise[{{(Sqrt[5] (-1 + l2) (2 + l2) (4 + l2) Sqrt[Gamma[5 - l2]/Gamma[6 + l2]])/
               ((-4 + l2) Gamma[3 - l2]), l2 ∈ Integers && 0 <= l2 <= 4}}, 0]
```

Looking at the expression inside the conditional,

```
Table[(Sqrt[5] (-1 + l2) (2 + l2) (4 + l2) Sqrt[Gamma[5 - l2]/Gamma[6 + l2]])/
      ((-4 + l2) Gamma[3 - l2]), {l2, 0, 4}]
   {1, 0, -Sqrt[2/7], 0, Indeterminate}
```

we do get the `Indeterminate` result noted in the OP, but you should also account for the following:

```
Limit[(Sqrt[5] (-1 + l2) (2 + l2) (4 + l2) Sqrt[Gamma[5 - l2]/Gamma[6 + l2]])/
      ((-4 + l2) Gamma[3 - l2]), l2 -> 4]
   Sqrt[2/7]
```

which is the expected answer. In short, the result is usually correct except at `l2 = 4`, and in that special case, a limit must be taken.

Comment: Very interesting!  Is there a way to identify whether a particular argument is an element of that countable set of values where taking the limit is not required? And, at those values where the limit is required, does the `ClebschGordan` function always yield `Indeterminate`?

Comment: Yes to the second, and no to the first. A careful person might consider taking limits first and then verifying if substitution gives the same result.